# ListView.builder returns a blank ModalBottomSheet, Google Places API

Tags: flutter, google-places-api, flutter-listview

This code returns a blank ModalBottomSheet. No error, just no content on the bottom sheet. _placeModel is a model object that should return data from Google Places API like address, website, etc.

```
    _onMarkerTapped() {
    showModalBottomSheet<void>(
        enableDrag: true,
        elevation: 10,
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(50.0))),
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _placeModel!.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.web),
                      title: const Text('Website'),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.home),
                      title: Text('Address: ${_placeModel![index].address}'),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.schedule),
                      title: const Text('Hours of Operation'),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.share),
                      title: const Text('Share'),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              });
        });
  }
```

Comment: _placeModel this list  is null

Comment: Hmm, not sure what you mean. I have a separate model called _placeModel in another file used to fetch the json from Google Places API. Any idea how to fix the blank screen?